# wayland display thread doesn't work(include wl_display_dispatch)

Tags: wayland

I am new about wayland protocol, but i should develop linux app regarding to wayland.
In short,
I have setup to display my app using wayland display, and I want to run input event loopat end of application, so I want to run display thread( include wl_display_dispath) and then excute proccessing events(input and other funcs). my psuedo code is below:

```
1. display_dispatch_thread()  
    while (rc != -1){  
    rc = wl_display_dispatch (wl->display);  
    }  

2. main app loop  

    pthread pid;  
    pthread_create (&pid, NULL, display_dispatch_thread, (void *) wl->display);  
    event_processing_loop();
```

when display_dispatch_thread was ran without thread, screen displayed worked and key event is worked, but
when display_dispatch_thread was ran as thread, there was no display on screen and key event didn't work.

For display and processing event queue, in my opinion, i should run display-dispatch in thread and then, finally process events separately.
Could you tell me how to fix my issue?
Thanks,